# Ant needs junit.jar on travis server

Tags: java, junit, ant, travis-ci

When I run `ant test` everything is cool, but when Travis runs the same command I get

$ ant test

> Buildfile:
>   /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build.xml
>
> compile:
>
> ```
> [mkdir] Created dir: /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build
> [javac] /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build.xml:28:
> ```
>
> warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to
>   build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
>       [javac] Compiling 12 source files to /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build
>       [javac] Note: /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/src/EventReceiver/EventsCollection.java
>   uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
>       [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
>
> test-compile:
>
> ```
> [mkdir] Created dir: /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build/test
> [javac] Compiling 3 source files to /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build/test
> ```
>
> test:
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> /home/travis/build/AwesomeTeamPlayer/event-receiver/build.xml:42:
>
> Problem: failed to create task or type junit
>
> Cause: the class
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTask was not found.
>
> ```
>     This looks like one of Ant's optional components. Action: Check that the appropriate optional JAR exists in
>     -/usr/share/ant/lib
>     -/home/travis/.ant/lib
>     -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument
> ```
>
> Do not panic, this is a common problem.
>
> The commonest cause is a missing JAR.
>
> This is not a bug; it is a configuration problem

When I changed `ant test` to `ant test -lib ./lib/junit-4.12.jar` in .travis.yml file I get the same error message :/

**.travis.yml**:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8

services:
  - docker

script: ant test -lib ./lib/junit-4.12.jar
```

**build.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<project name="Project name" basedir="." default="compile">

    <property name="src.dir" value="./src"/>
    <property name="build.dir" value="./build"/>
    <property name="lib.dir" value="./lib"/>
    <property name="test.dir" value="./tests"/>
    <property name="test.build.dir" value="./build/test"/>

    <path id="classpath.compile">
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/amqp-client-4.0.2.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/json-20170516.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <path id="classpath.test">
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/mockito-all-1.10.19.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/junit-4.12.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${lib.dir}/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"/>
    </path>

    <target name="compile" depends="">
        <delete dir="${build.dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build.dir}">
            <classpath refid="classpath.compile"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${test.build.dir}"/>
        <javac srcdir="${test.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
            <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
            <classpath refid="classpath.compile"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="test" depends="test-compile">
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath.test"/>
                <path refid="classpath.compile"/>
                <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="**/*Test.java" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>

    <target name="test-integration" depends="test-compile">
        <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <path refid="classpath.test"/>
                <path refid="classpath.compile"/>
                <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
            </classpath>
            <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
            <batchtest>
                <fileset dir="${test.dir}" includes="integration/**/*Test.java" />
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
    </target>
</project>
```

In **lib** dir I have

- amqp-client-4.0.2.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
- json-20170516.jar
- junit-4.12.jar
- mockito-all-1.10.19.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
- slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar

Answer (score 2):

I figure out what to do. I added

```
before_script:
   - sudo apt-get install ant-optional
```

and that fixed my problem ;)

Comment: According to the official Travis CI documentation, you are supposed to add this to before_install rather than before_script.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned on https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/installing-dependencies/:

> To install Ubuntu packages that are not included in the standard
>   precise, trusty, xenial, or bionic distribution, use apt-get in the
>   `before_install` step of your `.travis.yml`.

Which translates to adding the following to your **.travis.yml** file:

```
before_install:
   - sudo apt-get install ant-optional
```